# How to delay charging iPhone battery past 80% on iOS 12?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, charging

Note: I'm talking about **iOS 12**, not iOS 13.

---

A new feature of iOS 13 is delaying past 80% battery charging (as described here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210512 ). 

 
 The iPhone I have (iPhone 5s) cannot update to iOS 13 so I'm wondering how that functionality could be used/ imitated/ implemented on iOS 12 ? I would really like to use this feature, or an imitation of it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Maybe buy a charger that allows to set to a timer so that it stops charging after x minutes?

Comment: @JBallin I don‘t think that kind of chargers exist (after having searched on Google), and even if it did, I don‘t think it‘s very practical. But your help is appreciated !

Comment: Here’s [one](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LPSGBZS). The most practical solution is to buy a new iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I can't really afford a new iPhone currently.